# Why cannot <input type="hidden"> accept a boolean value from server side?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

From server side, I defined a new boolean value and set it into `<input>` tag, but browser couldn't detect it.

```
@{ var isAuthor = false; }
<input type="hidden" value="@isAuthor" />
```

After compiling, the result was: `<input type="hidden"></input>`

But, when I tried to convert `isAuthor` to a `string`, it should work:

```
@{ var isAuthor = false; }
<input type="hidden" value="@isAuthor.ToString()" />
```

Result: `<input type="hidden" value="false"></input>`

Why? Did I miss something?

Comment: _Did you miss something_ - No. Its just the way the razor engine works. If the value of an attribute is `null` or `false`, its not rendered - if you added `name="@isAuthor"` it would not be rendered either

Comment: You can also use `@Html.Hidden()`, it won't hide the value if it's false.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a Razor view engine feature called conditional attributes. The idea is to simplify the scenario, where you want or don't want to render the attribute based on the value. Previously you had to write `if` statement or use ternary operator to handle that, but with conditional attributes it is all much simplified.

With conditional attributes, if the value of an attribute is `null` or `false`, then the attribute is not rendered. If you want the value to be `false` you need to cast it to string, just like you did in the question.

You can read a great introduction to conditional Razor attributes in this [blog article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/201/cleaner-conditional-html-attributes-in-razor-web-pages)

Comment: Thanks. That's help :)